# Popup Control closes on fireing event

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, devexpress

i have two controls. First is a comment control, which allow the user to create, update and delete comments. It got own Menübar with add, safe, delete button. 
If someone want to add this control in his form it could be to big. So i have a second control, which is just a PopupContainerEdit with PopupControl. In the popupcontrol i add the commentcontrol. So i have an popupcommentcontrol and if someone want to add it in his form he just need a place for a small button of the popupcontaineredit.

My problem is, if i change the list of commentars (save, delete) in the commentarcontrol i fire a event, so that the popup can check the change of the list. So the Popupcontrol know if there are comments or not and i can swap the icon of the button. The enduser directly see on the icon of the button if there are comments or not. But if i fire the event to tell my popup "hey the list changes" the popup window get closed.

Is there a possibility to stop this close if i fire the event?

regards

Comment: Please explain your problem precisely. It is very confusing to understand your scenario. Thanks.

Comment: In fact the problem is that i have a popupcontaineredit which close its popupform if i fire my own event in it. Is it possible to prevent this closing?

Comment: It would be great if you paste your sample code in the question. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ59552.aspx